# Reading stream of integers in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to write a very simple OCaml program which will take a single line of ints separated by spaces e.g.

1 2 5 8 12 363 9

and store this as a list of ints i.e. [1;2;5;8;12;363;9]. How do I do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#require "str";;

let list_of_line line = Str.split (Str.regexp_string " ") line |> List.map int_of_string
```

Comment: "store this as a list of int": you need to convert the split values too (although OP doesn't say how he plans to use the list afterwards).